# Modelling health using differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

Note: this is mathematics question but necessarily involves some non mathematical concepts. I hope that we can consider it to be a good fit for this site. If not, happy to close, and it will still have been a worthwhile exercise to write it all out anyway.

I suddenly have a lot of free time and I feel like making 'something'. I decided to create a simulation of sorts. As part of this I need to model simple people. 3 of the attributes that describe a person are:

- Nutrition ($N$) - passively decays over time but can be increased
  when a person eats
- Energy ($E$) - passively decays while a person is awake. Can increase
  when a person is sleeping
- Health ($H$) - can increase or decrease depending on state of $N$ and
  $E$.

I would like to have a system of differential equations that governs the interaction of these variables. I suspect that I only need help with one of them, and once I have practiced the technique I should be OK to handle the others on my own. So with that in mind, I will focus on $E$ (during the awake state) here. Note: I would prefer to have continuous functions come out of this. So no max or min functions.

**Properties**

1. All variables are strictly between 0 and 1.
2. $E$ always decays over time.
3. $E$ has a long term upper bound of $H$. A healthier person has a higher
   capacity for energy reserves. So if a person ends up in a situation when $E>H$ (presumably because $H$ was impacted by some event) then $E$ should decay rapidly.
4. A person with high $H$, high $N$ and high $E$ should have a low
   decay rate.
5. A person with low $E$ should have a low decay rate, since $E$ cannot be negative.
6. All else being equal, low $N$ leads to higher decay rate of $E$. A starving person runs out of energy faster.

From here on is where I need help

**Formal properties (attempted)**

1. This is already formal enough
2. $\frac{\partial E}{\partial t} < 0$ (easy)
3. Starts to get tricky. Is this saying something about $\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial t\partial H}$ or $\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial t^2}$? Maybe $\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial t\partial H}\propto H-E = a(H-E)$ so that if $E>H$ then this is negative but otherwise positive. Need to be careful that this doesn't cause a violation of property 2 though.

4, 5 and 6 seem to be related to a single formal property. Are these saying something about $\frac{\partial^3E}{\partial t \partial H \partial N}$ or $\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial t \partial H}+\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial t \partial N}$

I'm hoping that once I can express these formal properties I can then integrate as far as they will go analytically and hopefully end up with an expression for $\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$.

Comment: Are you trying to say that Nutrition impacts Health by increasing Energy? Or rather is Energy a short term effect of Nutrition and Health a long term effect?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Energy is something that a person uses to perform most actions such as working. A person without energy is basically comatose. It can only be recovered by sleeping. It also slowly decays while awake. I suppose you can think of it as a short term effect of Nutrition but it is also impacted by Health.

Comment: A perfectly Healthy person only has so much energy to perform actions before needing to sleep. An unhealthy person has less energy to perform actions.

Comment: Or is that that someone with less energy is perceived to not be as healthy as someone with more energy? It works both ways, and you'll have to decide which is which for a mathematical treatment

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan I'm not sure I follow you. An unhealthy person loses energy fast and has a lower cap on energy than a healthy person. Energy is required to interact with the world. Zero energy means no interactions (forced sleep). Zero health means death. Zero nutrition mean starvation (rapid depletion of energy, no energy recovery even when sleeping, rapid decay of health, soon leading to death.

Comment: My global impression is that your issue could gain to be considered as a thermodynamics problem (https://math.berkeley.edu/~evans/entropy.and.PDE.pdf)

Comment: @JeanMarie an interesting thought that smells right. Looking through your document now.

Comment: $dE/dt$ can definitely be positive ("Can increase when a person is sleeping").

Comment: @David we are focusing on the awake state.

Answer (score 1):

My candidate answer (I will promote to accepted answer if no-one raises any valid objections after some time).

To satisfy properties 1 and 3, I decided to employ a [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) transformation $E=S(F,H)$ so that $F$ can take on any real value and $S$ will convert it to a value between $0$ and $H$. I can then model $F$ as a simpler function $F(t, N, H)$.

Next step is to decompose changes in $F$.
$$dF(t,N,H)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial F}{\partial N}dN+\frac{\partial F}{\partial H}dH$$

I can't see how there is any use for the last 2 terms so then I only need to worry about how $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$ evolves. Not sure if the following notation is OK but here goes.

$$d\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(t,N,H)=\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial t^2}dt+\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial t \partial N}dN+\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial t\partial H}dH$$

I don't think I need $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial t^2}$ for anything and the other 2 can be constants to be tuned later.
$$d\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(t,N,H)=a.dN+b.dH$$
where $a, b > 0$. To get an expression for $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$ I integrate the components

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=\int a.dN+\int b.dH=aN+bH+c$$
where $c$ is another tune-able parameter.

Then we have

$$\Delta F(t, \Delta t,N,H)=\int_t^{t+\Delta t}(aN+bN+c)dt=(aN+bH+c)\Delta t$$

and finally
$$F_{t+\Delta t}=F_t+(aN+bH+c)\Delta t$$